# wget failed: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, debian, wget

I have the following command to copy the website,

as it tried to hit sun.com it got connection timed out.

I would like the wget to exclude the sun.com so that wget would proceed to the next thing.

Exisitng Issue

```
$ wget --recursive --page-requisites --adjust-extension --span-hosts --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/
.
.
2021-08-09 03:28:28 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]

2021-08-09 03:28:30 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]
.


Location: https : //packages. debian. org /robots.txt [following]
--2021-08-09 03:28:33--  https : //packages. debian. org /robots.txt
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|128.0.10.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’

packages.debian.org 100%[===================>]      24  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2021-08-09 03:28:34 (19.1 MB/s) - ‘packages.debian.org/robots.txt’ saved [24/24]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2021-08-09 03:28:34--  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Resolving wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)... 137.254.16.75
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:28:56--  (try: 2)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:29:19--  (try: 3)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:29:43--  (try: 4)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:30:08--  (try: 5)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:30:34--  (try: 6)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2021-08-09 03:31:01--  (try: 7)  http ://wwws. sun. com/ robots.txt
Connecting to wwws.sun.com (wwws.sun.com)|137.254.16.75|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

Expected $wget to save the whole website without timeouts, if there are timeouts then wget would skip the timeout connections.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

```
wget \
     --recursive \                      # Download the whole site.
     --page-requisites \                # Get all assets/elements (CSS/JS/images).
     --adjust-extension \               # Save files with .html on the end.
     --span-hosts \                     # Include necessary assets from offsite as well.
     --convert-links \                  # Update links to still work in the static version.
     --restrict-file-names=windows \    # Modify filenames to work in Windows as well.
     --domains yoursite.com \           # Do not follow links outside this domain.
     --no-parent \                      # Don't follow links outside the directory you pass in.
         yoursite.com/whatever/path     # The URL to download
```

Comment: It did not help